# Why my CAPS status resets every time i change language

Tags: keyboard-layout

Edit: I did a new question as this is hapening for years!

I will post a new question every year about this.

Hi there and greetings from Kefalonia/Greece.

I have a little issue: Every time i change the keyboard's language using alt+shift, my CAPS status resets and i have to press again the CAPSLOCK key to write in capital letters.

Any Ideas on how do i get it to stop reseting?

Comment: no one really knows anything, lets see how will it go with 16.04

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of your new question since it is presumably the same issue. You might want to edit the new one and mention that you've had this problem for years.

Comment: Yes it' a yearly problem....

Comment: then please edit your new question and mention this. You should clarify that you've had it for years, mention that it happens even if you change the default key combination for switching languages, that it happens with other non-Greek languages, that it happens both when switching En->Gr and Gr->En etc. Basically, the more detail you add, the better your chances of getting an answer.